# How can I pull data from console objects?

Tags: console, google-tag-manager

I want to pull user data from the console object as attached images . This my website is integrated with booking engine & one client booked then i get one object in console . As in the object user data is availble like email,Phone number . Can you please advise how can i access on consdole objects ?

I've tried in manay options but it's not working

I am expecting a way to pull the data & create variable for google tag manager so i can send this data to my marketing tools.